# How connect php and sql server 2008 R2 using wamp server

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2, wamp

Already changed file php.ini 
And the index.php file contains:

```
<?php
$server = 'name/SQLEXPRESS';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'namepc', 'pw');
if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong');
}
?>
```

And the error message on the localhost is:

Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]:. (severity 14)

Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 
Something went wrong

Comment: Check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php#81300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already made it!
Just create a new usser on managment studio and linked it the new accound to your php code.